# What's wrong with this XML/XSD?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have a simple XSD and an even simpler XML. But the Java 2 XML validation fails. (using javax.xml.validation)

Here is my XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:tns="http://foo.com/darnit"
     targetNamespace="http://foo.com/darnit">

   <xsd:element name="Person" type="tns:PersonType"/>

   <xsd:simpleType name="nameType">
     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
   </xsd:simpleType>

   <xsd:complexType name="PersonType">
     <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2" name="FirstName" type="tns:nameType"/>
       <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LastName" type="tns:nameType"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

And here is the sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Person xmlns="http://foo.com/darnit">
  <FirstName>John</FirstName>
  <FirstName>Michael</FirstName>
  <LastName>Smith</LastName>
</Person>
```

Here is the error message I get:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'FirstName'. One of '{FirstName}' is expected.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.StreamValidatorHelper.validate(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaValidator.validate(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
```

If I qualify the XML with namespace prefix, it works!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo:Person xmlns:foo="http://foo.com/darnit">
  <FirstName>John</FirstName>
  <FirstName>Michael</FirstName>
  <LastName>Smith</LastName>
</foo:Person>
```

But my XSD allows unqualified elements!

Do I have to set a property on SchemaFactory, Schema, or the Validator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add elementFormDefault=qualified to you schame, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:tns="http://foo.com/darnit"
 targetNamespace="http://foo.com/darnit"
 elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

Then, all elements will be in the target namespace per default.

All globally declared elements will belong to the target namespace. However the "elementFormDefault" attribute controls wether or not local elements also belong to the target namespace, i.e. "are qualified". Some people obviously prefer the "unqualified" style that you inadvertently created. However, I have never seen a good argument in favor of it.

Comment: Unreal! Thanks, that was it. I misunderstood elementFormDefault="qualified". I thought it meant that all elements must belong to an explicitly declared namespace. Thanks!

Comment: @raminr Updated answer for better explanation.

Comment: Thanks... Saw that. Great explanation. This stuff is like a puzzle which only makes sense after it's solved. :-)